# Apollo Client useMutation does not call the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am trying to use `useMutation` for my graphql API but it does not seems to make any call,

here is the code

```js
export async function bulkImport(importRequest: BulkImportRequest): Promise<string> {
  const [postBulkImport, { data }] = useMutation(postBulkImportRequest, {
    variables: importRequest,
  });
  await postBulkImport({ variables: importRequest });
  return data?.requestId;
}
```

and the I call `bulkImport` in my React component.

I am trying to rewrite below code using useMutation instead of `mutate`. Bellow code is working fine.

```js
export async function bulkImport(importRequest: BulkImportRequest): Promise<string> {
  const response = await mutate(postBulkImportRequest, importRequest);
  return response?.data?.postBulkImportRequest?.requestId;
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing when I use useMutation, I am actually not sure if they are the same.

any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`useMutation` is a [React Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and as such can only be used [from the top level of a React functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

Nothing happens when you try and use it from your `bulkImport` function because it's not at the top level of a React component.

You'll need to (quite dramatically) rewrite your component in order to work with `useMutation` successfully.